# Python assign different variables to a class object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, oop, object

This is a general python question. Is it possible to assign different variables to a class object and then perform different set of operations on those variables? I'm trying to reduce code but maybe this isn't how it works. For example, I'm trying to do something like this:

Edit: here is an abstract of the class and methods:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def query(self, query):
        self.df = self.df.query(query)
        return self

    def fill(self, filter):
        self.df.update(df.filter(like=filter).mask(lambda x: x == 0).ffill(1))
        return self

    def diff(self, cols=None, axis=1):
        diff = self.df[self.df.columns[~self.df.columns.isin(cols)]].diff(axis=axis)
        self.df = diff.join(self.df[self.df.columns.difference(diff.columns)])
        return self

    def melt(self, cols, var=None, value=None):
        return pd.melt(self.df, id_vars=columns, var_name=var, value_name=value)
```

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df = Class(df)
df = df.query(query).forward_fill(include)

df_1 = df.diff(cols).melt(cols)

df_2 = df.melt(cols)
```

`df_1` and `df_2` should have different values, however they are the same as `df_1`. This issue is resolved if I use the class like this:

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df_1 = Class(df_1)
df_2 = Class(df_2)

df_1 = df_1.query(query).forward_fill(include)
df_2 = df_2.query(query).forward_fill(include)

df_1 = df_1.diff(cols).melt(cols)

df_2 = df_2.melt(cols)
```

This results in extra code. Is there a better way to do this where you can use an object differently on different variables, or do I have to create seperate objects if I'm trying to have two variables perform separate operations and return different values?

Comment: Can you show us what `oper_1` and `oper_2` are doing?

Comment: They're `pandas` dataframe manipulations chained together

Comment: Show a definition of `Class` that lets us reproduce the error. You also need to include both the expected and observed output.

Comment: `2 + 5` and `3 + 4` produce the same output as well, but that doesn't mean either one is wrong.

Comment: @chepner added class details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `return self` statement in the `diff`- method you return the reference of the object. The same thing happens after the `melt` method. But in that two methods you allreadey manipulated the origin `df`.

Here:

```py
1 df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
2
3 df = Class(df)
4 df = df.query(query).forward_fill(include)
5 
6 df_1 = df.diff(cols).melt(cols)
```

the `df` has the same values like `df_1`. I guess the `melt` method without other args then cols arguments only assigns col names or something like that. Subsequently `df_2=df.melt(cols)` would have the same result like `df_2=df_1.melt(cols)`.

If you want to work with one object, you dont should use `self.df=...` in your class methods, because this changes the instance value of `df`. You only need to write `df = ...`  and than return `Class(df)`.

For example:

```py
def diff(self, cols=None, axis=1):
    diff = self.df[self.df.columns[~self.df.columns.isin(cols)]].diff(axis=axis)
    df = diff.join(self.df[self.df.columns.difference(diff.columns)])
    return Class(df)
```

Best regards